# Please guide me for UI design Workflow

Tags: workflow, interface-design, visualization

I have just started design for mobile apps. My question is: in the beginning of the design process I have so many ideas, but I am not able to decide which one visually looks great... Designing all ideas that came up is very time consuming method. Any suggestions to a good method?

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, if you have an idea, go with it to some degree. Start with a sketch, if it still looks good, move onto a wireframe, and then a full mockup. Save them all and compare at a later date.

Take into account peer feedback from a broad selection. Get feedback from other designers, and people who don't know the first thing about design, the later usually focus their comments on the usability of it. This is a crucial step in first considerations as dependent on your personality you can either under or over appreciate your own work.

But most importantly, don't always see your ideas as a blueprint that must be followed to the exact mark. Take bits and pieces from other ideas and put them together into a concept collage of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Find great sample and measure your ideas with it.. if your idea is good enough to stand together with sample - go on with it.